# Is there any way to set expiry headers in asp.net without making changes in IIS 6 Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, expires-header, cache-expiration

I Need To Set Expiry Headers In my Asp.net code.. Is there any way through which I Can Add expiry Headers through code.?

I Have tried adding the following code in my asp page

`<% System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader( "Cache-Control","no-cache");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = 0;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");%>`
`<%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" Location="Client" VaryByParam="None" %>`

and added the following in my c# page...

`Response.AddHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 2014 16:00:00 GMT");`


AND
`Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
 Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600));
 Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3600));`

and added this to web,config file

`<clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT"           cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />`

Comment: @SonerGönül Yup.. Edited the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(yourCalculatedDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define it per page like below

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

or you can do it in declaritive way by doing it in your aspx page like below

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

Comment: Is'nt the OutputCache directive just caching the page on the server? IMHO the OP talks about enabling client-side caching with response headers, which is different.

Comment: @marcel acually OutputCache is tuneable base on the location value and if you didnt define location as per microsoft "the page output can be cached on all cache-capable network devices that are involved in the response. These include the requesting client, the origin server, and any proxy servers through which the response passes."

Comment: Nope Not Helping.. :(